# phonegap build and Facebook Plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I can not solve it!
I'm working on Phonegap Build, and want to add a facebook login for the app.
but plugin seems not to work !

here is the error I receive : 
"Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on init!"

for more information my phonegap version is : 3.1.0
and I use Hydration (Maybe gives you an idea)
and here is the simple code I use:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
        <button onclick="me()">Me</button>
        <!--<button onclick="getSession()">Get session</button>-->
        <button onclick="getLoginStatus()">Get login</button>
        <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
        <button onclick="facebookWallPost()">facebookWallPost</button>
        <button onclick="publishStoryFriend()">friendstory</button>

        <div id="data">loading ...</div>

        <!--<script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>-->
        <!-- cordova -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
        <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
        <!-- facebook js sdk -->
        <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>

        <script>
             <!-- These are the notifications that are displayed to the user through pop-ups if the above JS files does not exist in the same directory-->
            if ((typeof cordova == 'undefined') && (typeof Cordova == 'undefined')) alert('Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly');
            if (typeof CDV == 'undefined') alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
            if (typeof FB == 'undefined') alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.login event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.logout event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.sessionChange event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.statusChange event');
                               });

            /*function getSession() {
                alert("session: " + JSON.stringify(FB.getSession()));
            }
            */
            function getLoginStatus() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                  if (response.status == 'connected') {
                                  alert('logged in');
                                  } else {
                                  alert('not logged in');
                                  }
                                  });
            }
            var friendIDs = [];
            var fdata;
            function me() {
                FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },  function(response) {
                       if (response.error) {
                       alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                       } else {
                       var data = document.getElementById('data');
                       fdata=response.data;
                       console.log("fdata: "+fdata);
                       response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                                             var d = document.createElement('div');
                                             d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+"/>"+item.name;
                                             data.appendChild(d);
                                             });
                       }
                    var friends = response.data;
                    console.log(friends.length); 
                    for (var k = 0; k < friends.length && k < 200; k++) {
                        var friend = friends[k];
                        var index = 1;

                        friendIDs[k] = friend.id;
                        //friendsInfo[k] = friend;
                    }
                    console.log("friendId's: "+friendIDs);
                       });
            }

            function logout() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                          alert('logged out');
                          });
            }

            function login() {
                FB.login(
                         function(response) {
                         if (response.session) {
                         alert('logged in');
                         } else {
                         alert('not logged in');
                         }
                         },
                         { scope: "email" }
                         );
            }


            function facebookWallPost() {
                console.log('Debug 1');
                var params = {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
                  };
                console.log(params);
                FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
            }

            function publishStoryFriend() {
                randNum = Math.floor ( Math.random() * friendIDs.length ); 

                var friendID = friendIDs[randNum];
                if (friendID == undefined){
                    alert('please click the me button to get a list of friends first');
                }else{
                    console.log("friend id: " + friendID );
                    console.log('Opening a dialog for friendID: ', friendID);
                    var params = {
                        method: 'feed',
                        to: friendID.toString(),
                        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
                    };
                    FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                                      try {
                                      alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                                      FB.init({ appId: "[myAppID]", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
                                      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
                                      } catch (e) {
                                      alert(e);
                                      }
                                      }, false);
            </script>
        <div id="log"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/3.3.0" id = "com.phonegap.polimiSajjad" version = "0.0.3">

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />

<name>Sajjad App v0.0.4</name>
<description>just a test app</description>
<author href="sajjadsalehi.webadua.com" email="aghsajjy@yahoo.com">sajjad salehi</author>
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="[myAppID]" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Polimi Students Market" />
</gap:plugin>
<icon src="icon.jpg" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong in setting the package name on facebook app settings!
does anyone have any idea what is the name of the package I should enter on facebook settings? Thanks

Comment: name of package in facebook settings would be com.phonegap.polimiSajjad i.e id of widget tag in config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following code on page load before calling any facebook functions.

```
FB.init({
  appId: "your facebook id",
  nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
  useCachedDialogs: false,
  status: true
});
```